# Dapper MultiMap doesn't work with splitOn with NULL value

Tags: dapper

I have a problem with MultiMaps in dapper trying to split on column that contains `NULL`. Dapper seems not to instantiate object and my mapping function receives `null` instead of object.

Here's my new test:

```
    class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }
    class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
    public void TestMultiMapWithSplitWithNullValue()
    {
        var sql = @"select 1 as id, 'abc' as name, NULL as description, 'def' as name";
        var product = connection.Query<Product, Category, Product>(sql, (prod, cat) =>
        {
            prod.Category = cat;
            return prod;
        }, splitOn: "description").First();
        // assertions
        product.Id.IsEqualTo(1);
        product.Name.IsEqualTo("abc");
        product.Category.IsNotNull();
        product.Category.Id.IsEqualTo(0);
        product.Category.Name.IsEqualTo("def");
        product.Category.Description.IsNull();
    }
```

**The line that fails is `product.Category.IsNotNull();` due to the fact that `cat` passed to mapping function is `null`.**

I've also added this method to Assert class:

```
public static void IsNotNull(this object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Expected not null");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would love to help, pinged Paul on twitter who write github for windows. I know they are working hard to get this line ending problem tractable

Comment: @SamSaffron - thanks for your comment. If you let me know once it's sorted out, I can push my changes. You could copy the test from my post, though - it's pretty obvious where the changes should go ;-) PS. I love github for windows. Let me know if I could be of any help with testing.

Comment: I've sent a PR for Dapper that should make these line ending problems go away. Let me know if they still show up. Moral of the story: * Copy-Paste [this file](https://gist.github.com/2802523#file_the+original+guy+used+autocrlffalse) as `.gitattributes` if the original guy used `autocrlf=false` * Copy-Paste [this file](https://gist.github.com/2802523#file_the+original+guy+used+autocrlftrue) as `.gitattributes` if he used `autocrlf=true`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is "by-design" though I would be ok to revisit it.

In particular this behaviour is there to help with left joins. Take this for example:

```
cnn.Query<Car,Driver>("select * from Cars c left join Drivers on c.Id = CarId",
   (c,d) => {c.Driver = d; return c;})
```

Trouble is that if we allow a "blanket" creation of a `Driver` object, every `Car` is going to have a `Driver` even ones where the join failed.

To work around we could scan the entire segment being split and ensure ALL values are `NULL` before mapping a `NULL` object. This will have a very minor perf impact on the multi mapper.

To workaround for your case, you could insert a surrogate column:

```
var sql = @"select 1 as id, 'abc' as name, '' as split, 
            NULL as description, 'def' as name";
    var product = connection.Query<Product, Category, Product>(sql, (prod, cat) =>
    {
        prod.Category = cat;
        return prod;
    }, splitOn: "split").First();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I see your point. I've implemented similar workaround in my project using primary key of `Drivers` table. Blank surrogate column forces object creation for each row, even the ones that failed left join, so in order to find missing records I would need to check all the properties myself in mapping function anyway. It would be great if Dapper could handle it in a generic way instead of me checking multiple properties for `NULL` in multiple maps. Maybe some flag to improve pefr? A more descriptive example (http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) would be welcomed, too.

Comment: I just ran into this issue and was not aware of this behavior ahead of time.  I'd be interested in at least having a `splitOnNull:true` flag to avoid this problem.  Will have to use surrogate columns until then.

Comment: Isn't this example flawed, in that you have a column called "name" twice?

Comment: I would prefer to take the performance hit or `splitOnNull:true`. This is idiosyncratic behaviour that my fellow developers need to 'know' about to use Dapper. I guess typically you'd be joining on a foreign key, so that field could be a reliable splitter. But I still don't like that a developer just has to know about this, and this kind of bug can easily slip through QA if a field happens not to be null.

Comment: @Patrick the split is between the name columns, so the first name is stored in `prod.name`, the second in `cat.name`. (The repetition was probably deliberate to illustrate this.)

Comment: I've discussed with my team and we've decided we will remove all Dapper sub-object population rather than expect developers to be aware of it, (at the expense of extra queries). Fully respect that Dapper's founding philosophy is that ORM's have opinions though!

Comment: No way!  Please don't do that. This is a key feature.  We would have to move away from dapper if you did.

Comment: Hi, has a fix found for spliton null issue ? I see an issue #266 in github dapper thread that says the issue has been resolved. But in the latest dapper version 1.50.0 the issue still persists.

Comment: This seems like an odd way to go on this issue. You are basically saying "If the first value is null, the whole object is probably null". Seems like it would make more sense to take the small performance hit to scan the whole object to verify all of the values are null before assuming it is null. Or at least provide a function to switch between the two, as someone else suggested. Looks like I am going to be in the same boat as Chris and will have to build the objects myself instead of relying on Dapper to split them for me.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue, i'm forced to select a fake 'split' columns to make Dapper fill my object instead of just null it;

My workaround :

```
    string req = @"
SELECT
    T1.a as PropA,
    T1.b as PropB,

    1 as Split,
    T2.a as PropA,
    T2.b as PropB,

    1 as Split,
    ...
FROM
    xxx T1,
    yyy T2,
    ...";
    using (var db = new OracleConnection(...))
    {
        return db.Query(
            req,
            (T1, T2) => {
                ...
            },
            splitOn:'Split,Split,...');
    }
```

Dapper should have an option to avoid the `splitOn:'Split,Split,...'`

Answer (score 3):

For all who wants visualization :

Dapper splits by the last equal column name :

[image]

Let's swap location of columns :

[image]

null problem :

[image]

Swapped column null :

[image]

Spliton to the rescue :

[image]