# Dapper doesn't fill entity, even with the right `splitOn`?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper, .net-4.6

Looking at this *simplified*  SQL Server query :

```
set @userid2=...

SELECT *,
       SPLIT = '',
       userid2 = @userid2

    FROM   Comments c
           JOIN Users u
                ON  ...
```

I'm using this *partially working* code to execute the SP :

```
 await c.QueryAsync<Comment, User, SqlInt, CommentWithSenderAndUserId2>(@"insertCommentByImageId",
(message1, user, myint) => new CommentWithSenderAndUserId2 
                                {
                                  User = user,
                                  Comment = message1, 
                                  UserId2 = myint.MyIntValue
                                },
  new {imageid = imageId, userid1 = userid1, comment = comment}, //parms
  splitOn: "UserID,split",  //splits
  commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure //command type
 )
```

As you can see I'm returnning all columns both from `Comments` and `Users` **PLUS** some `int` value.

Well I know that I can't  return an `int` value just like that ,  I need to return an entity .

That's why I've created this dummy class to hold an `int` value :

```
public class SqlInt
    {
        public int MyIntValue { get; set; }
    }
```

And as you can see , it is part of the generic types :

```
c.QueryAsync<Comment, User, SqlInt, CommentWithSenderAndUserId2>
```

So basically I'm taking a `Comment` , `User`, `SqlInt` and put it all in `CommentWithSenderAndUserId2`

So where is the problem ?

The int value of my dummy class never gets filled and it's always `0` ( other entities filled just fine)

[image]

[I did read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10791648/859154) ( as I did in my SP) that I should add a splitter column  such as :

```
   SELECT *, 
           SPLIT = '',       <----------- Here
           userid2 = @userid2
```

**Question**

What am I doing wrong and How can I get myInt value filled   ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found my silly mistake.
Problem was that I've created an entity to hold an `int` value, right ?

```
  public class SqlInt
    {
        public int MyIntValue { get; set; }
    }
```

The name of the property is `MyIntValue`. If so , Why did I do this :

```
SELECT *,
           SPLIT = '',
           userid2 = @userid2
```

Rather than  the right approach :

```
SELECT *,
           SPLIT = '',
           MyIntValue = @userid2 <---- change is here
```

Now I do see that right value.